# System freezes on copying or pasting

Tags: freeze, copy, paste

I am using LibreOffice

Version: 6.0.7.3
Build-ID: 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10
CPU-Threads: 12; BS: Linux 4.15; UI-Render: Standard; VCL: gtk3;

on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. When copying something, the system freezes for a couple of minutes.
When running top in console before copying, i can see process gjs on 100% cpu and using all RAM and Swap. System needs several minutes then runs smoothly again. kern.log shows this:

```
Jan  8 19:29:54 Ubuntu-Desktop kernel: [ 2069.787482] gjs[11334]: segfault at 0 ip 00007efd97fd7258 sp 00007ffc9c1d8a80 error 4 in libgjs.so.0.0.0[7efd97faf000+c7000]
Jan  8 19:33:52 Ubuntu-Desktop kernel: [ 2307.731431] gjs[20499]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f49dde0c258 sp 00007ffe5fd44f60 error 4 in libgjs.so.0.0.0[7f49ddde4000+c7000]
Jan  8 19:36:19 Ubuntu-Desktop kernel: [ 2454.734207] gjs[22357]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f2ab50ef258 sp 00007ffd4ad3cb00 error 4 in libgjs.so.0.0.0[7f2ab50c7000+c7000]
Jan  8 19:38:46 Ubuntu-Desktop kernel: [ 2601.547273] gjs[23399]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f8b61934258 sp 00007ffc5fe61f10 error 4 in libgjs.so.0.0.0[7f8b6190c000+c7000]
```

In Writer this only happens every 10th time or so, but in Calc every single copy-action triggers this. Nautilus also frequently triggers this bug when pasting files, with same symptoms occuring.

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
$ free -h
          Gesamt   belegt    frei        gemns. Puffer/Cache verfügbar
Speicher:         15G        1,9G         11G         63M        1,8G         13G
Auslagerungsspeicher:         29G          0B         29G

$ sysctl vm.swappiness 
vm.swappiness = 60

$ sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware                
       Beschreibung: BIOS
       Hersteller: American Megatrends Inc.
       Physische ID: 0
       Version: 1101
       date: 02/27/2018
       Größe: 64KiB
       Kapazität: 15MiB
       Fähigkeiten: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       Beschreibung: Systemspeicher
       Physische ID: 42
       Steckplatz: Systemplatine oder Hauptplatine
       Größe: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          Beschreibung: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2018-07-12 13:19+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18719)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2018-07-12 13:19+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18719) [leer]
          Physische ID: 0
          Steckplatz: ChannelA-DIMM1
     *-bank:1
          Beschreibung: DIMM DDR4 Synchron Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2800 MHz (0,4 ns)
          Produkt: F4-3000C15-8GVKB
          Hersteller: G-Skill
          Physische ID: 1
          Seriennummer: 00000000
          Steckplatz: ChannelA-DIMM2
          Größe: 8GiB
          Breite: 64 bits
          Takt: 2800MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:2
          Beschreibung: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2018-07-12 13:19+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18719)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2018-07-12 13:19+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18719) [leer]
          Physische ID: 2
          Steckplatz: ChannelB-DIMM1
     *-bank:3
          Beschreibung: DIMM DDR4 Synchron Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2800 MHz (0,4 ns)
          Produkt: F4-3000C15-8GVKB
          Hersteller: G-Skill
          Physische ID: 3
          Seriennummer: 00000000
          Steckplatz: ChannelB-DIMM2
          Größe: 8GiB
          Breite: 64 bits
          Takt: 2800MHz (0.4ns)
  *-cache:0
       Beschreibung: L1 Cache
       Physische ID: 48
       Steckplatz: L1 Cache
       Größe: 384KiB
       Kapazität: 384KiB
       Fähigkeiten: synchronous internal write-back unified
       Konfiguration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       Beschreibung: L2 Cache
       Physische ID: 49
       Steckplatz: L2 Cache
       Größe: 1536KiB
       Kapazität: 1536KiB
       Fähigkeiten: synchronous internal write-back unified
       Konfiguration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       Beschreibung: L3 Cache
       Physische ID: 4a
       Steckplatz: L3 Cache
       Größe: 12MiB
       Kapazität: 12MiB
       Fähigkeiten: synchronous internal write-back unified
       Konfiguration: level=3
  *-memory UNGEFORDERT
       Beschreibung: Memory controller
       Produkt: 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 1f.2
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       Version: 00
       Breite: 32 bits
       Takt: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       Fähigkeiten: bus_master
       Konfiguration: latency=0
       Ressourcen: memory:df344000-df347fff
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider disabling GNOME Extensions. In my case the culprit was GSConnect