# Why is Libreoffice crashing my whole system?

Tags: libreoffice, freeze, crash

I am running Kubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. When I use Libreoffice (currently 6.0.7.3) Writer, it frequently crashes my whole system. The display freezes for about a minute and after that, I get back to the login screen to start a new session. I can't reproduce it, but I can say that it has always happened while I was typing text, nothing fancy.

Here is an extract from my `/var/log/syslog` right after restarting the system:

```
Mar 26 10:20:55 t460s kernel: [ 4017.752650] [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 9:0:0x86dffffd, in Xorg [1213], reason: Hang on rcs0, action: reset
Mar 26 10:20:55 t460s kernel: [ 4017.752664] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang
Mar 26 10:20:59 t460s kernel: [ 4021.917063] asynchronous wait on fence i915:kwin_x11[1500]/1:af3e timed out
Mar 26 10:21:01 t460s kernel: [ 4024.327712] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 3
Mar 26 10:21:01 t460s upowerd[1530]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:046D:C019.0003
Mar 26 10:21:01 t460s upowerd[1530]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0
Mar 26 10:21:01 t460s upowerd[1530]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3
Mar 26 10:21:03 t460s kernel: [ 4025.725184] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang
Mar 26 10:21:11 t460s kernel: [ 4033.725157] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang
Mar 26 10:21:15 t460s kernel: [ 4037.801122] usb 1-3: new low-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Mar 26 10:21:15 t460s kernel: [ 4037.956590] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c019
Mar 26 10:21:15 t460s kernel: [ 4037.956600] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Mar 26 10:21:15 t460s kernel: [ 4037.956606] usb 1-3: Product: USB Optical Mouse
Mar 26 10:21:15 t460s kernel: [ 4037.956612] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Logitech
Mar 26 10:21:15 t460s kernel: [ 4037.960038] input: Logitech USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:046D:C019.0004/input/input22
Mar 26 10:21:15 t460s kernel: [ 4038.017538] hid-generic 0003:046D:C019.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
Mar 26 10:21:15 t460s mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3"
Mar 26 10:21:15 t460s mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 8 was not an MTP device
Mar 26 10:21:15 t460s upowerd[1530]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:046D:C019.0004
Mar 26 10:21:15 t460s upowerd[1530]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0
Mar 26 10:21:15 t460s upowerd[1530]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3
Mar 26 10:21:19 t460s kernel: [ 4041.757170] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang
Mar 26 10:21:31 t460s kernel: [ 4053.757186] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang
Mar 26 10:21:45 t460s kernel: [ 4067.741187] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang
Mar 26 10:22:01 t460s kernel: [ 4083.741187] i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang
Mar 26 10:22:01 t460s kernel: [ 4084.457399] kauditd_printk_skb: 8 callbacks suppressed
Mar 26 10:22:01 t460s kernel: [ 4084.457401] audit: type=1400 audit(1585214521.816:1993): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="unlink" profile="libreoffice-soffice//null-/usr/bin/kdeinit4" name="/run/user/1000/ksocket-jan/kdeinit4__0" pid=15441 comm="kdeinit4" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Mar 26 10:22:01 t460s org.kde.ActivityManager[1370]: The X11 connection broke: I/O error (code 1)
Mar 26 10:22:01 t460s org.kde.ActivityManager[1370]: XIO:  fatal IO error 2 (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden) on X server ":0"
Mar 26 10:22:01 t460s org.kde.ActivityManager[1370]:       after 1250 requests (1250 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Mar 26 10:22:01 t460s org.kde.kuiserver[1370]: kuiserver: Fatal IO error: client killed
Mar 26 10:22:01 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1370]: The X11 connection broke: I/O error (code 1)
Mar 26 10:22:01 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1370]: XIO:  fatal IO error 0 (Erfolg) on X server ":0"
Mar 26 10:22:01 t460s org.kde.KScreen[1370]:       after 791 requests (791 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Mar 26 10:22:01 t460s org.kde.kglobalaccel[1370]: The X11 connection broke: I/O error (code 1)
Mar 26 10:22:01 t460s org.kde.kglobalaccel[1370]: XIO:  fatal IO error 25 (Unpassender IOCTL (I/O-Control) für das Gerät) on X server ":0"
Mar 26 10:22:01 t460s org.kde.kglobalaccel[1370]:       after 1487 requests (1487 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Mar 26 10:22:01 t460s org.kde.kwalletd5[1370]: The X11 connection broke: I/O error (code 1)
Mar 26 10:22:01 t460s org.kde.kwalletd5[1370]: XIO:  fatal IO error 25 (Unpassender IOCTL (I/O-Control) für das Gerät) on X server ":0"
Mar 26 10:22:01 t460s org.kde.kwalletd5[1370]:       after 789 requests (789 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Mar 26 10:22:01 t460s dbus-daemon[1370]: [session uid=1000 pid=1370] Activating service name='org.kde.kglobalaccel' requested by ':1.17' (uid=1000 pid=1486 comm="/usr/bin/ksmserver " label="unconfined")
Mar 26 10:22:02 t460s kernel: [ 4085.137070] [drm] Reducing the compressed framebuffer size. This may lead to less power savings than a non-reduced-size. Try to increase stolen memory size if available in BIOS.
Mar 26 10:22:02 t460s org.kde.kglobalaccel[1370]: qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
Mar 26 10:22:02 t460s org.kde.kglobalaccel[1370]: Could not connect to any X display.
Mar 26 10:22:02 t460s dbus-daemon[1370]: [session uid=1000 pid=1370] Activated service 'org.kde.kglobalaccel' failed: Process org.kde.kglobalaccel exited with status 1
Mar 26 10:22:02 t460s sddm[1185]: Display server stopped.
Mar 26 10:22:02 t460s sddm[1185]: Running display stop script  "/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xstop"
Mar 26 10:22:02 t460s sddm[1185]: Removing display ":0" ...
Mar 26 10:22:02 t460s sddm[1185]: Adding new display on vt 1 ...
Mar 26 10:22:02 t460s sddm[1185]: Loading theme configuration from ""
Mar 26 10:22:02 t460s sddm[1185]: Display server starting...
Mar 26 10:22:02 t460s sddm[1185]: Running: /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{ebcd8421-ec41-4952-8fae-c9ac0fee4c97} -background none -noreset -displayfd 20 -seat seat0 vt1
Mar 26 10:22:02 t460s sddm-helper[1317]: [PAM] Closing session
Mar 26 10:22:02 t460s sddm-helper[1317]: [PAM] Ended.
Mar 26 10:22:02 t460s org.kde.ActivityManager[1370]: Closing SQL connection:  "kactivities_db_resources_140647670131840_readwrite"
```

I have no idea what could be the problem. Does anybody?

Added on March 28:

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
N1CET37W (1.05)
```

And

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t 1,2
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.8 present.

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
        Manufacturer: LENOVO
        Product Name: 20FAS05P00
        Version: ThinkPad T460s
        Serial Number: PC0B704Z
        UUID: 1FBDB0CC-2928-11B2-A85C-E61EC0A73495
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_20FA_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad T460s
        Family: ThinkPad T460s

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: LENOVO
        Product Name: 20FAS05P00
        Version: Not Defined
        Serial Number: L1HF61S00XK
        Asset Tag: Not Available
        Features:
                Board is a hosting board
                Board is replaceable
        Location In Chassis: Not Available
        Chassis Handle: 0x0000
        Type: Motherboard
        Contained Object Handles: 0
```

And

```
$ sudo lshw -C memory
  *-cache:0                 
      Beschreibung: L1 Cache
      Physische ID: 3
      Steckplatz: L1 Cache
      Größe: 64KiB
      Kapazität: 64KiB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      Fähigkeiten: synchronous internal write-back data                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      Konfiguration: level=1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  *-cache:1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      Beschreibung: L1 Cache                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      Physische ID: 4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      Steckplatz: L1 Cache                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      Größe: 64KiB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      Kapazität: 64KiB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      Fähigkeiten: synchronous internal write-back instruction                                                                                                                                                                                              
      Konfiguration: level=1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  *-cache:2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      Beschreibung: L2 Cache                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      Physische ID: 5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      Steckplatz: L2 Cache                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      Größe: 512KiB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      Kapazität: 512KiB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      Fähigkeiten: synchronous internal write-back unified                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      Konfiguration: level=2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  *-cache:3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      Beschreibung: L3 Cache                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      Physische ID: 6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      Steckplatz: L3 Cache                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      Größe: 4MiB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      Kapazität: 4MiB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      Fähigkeiten: synchronous internal write-back unified                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      Konfiguration: level=3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  *-memory                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      Beschreibung: Systemspeicher                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      Physische ID: 8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      Steckplatz: Systemplatine oder Hauptplatine                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      Größe: 20GiB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    *-bank:0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
          Beschreibung: SODIMM DDR4 Synchron 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)                                                                                                                                                                                               
          Hersteller: 0000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
          Physische ID: 0
          Seriennummer: 00000000
          Steckplatz: ChannelA-DIMM0
          Größe: 4GiB
          Breite: 64 bits
          Takt: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
    *-bank:1
          Beschreibung: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2018-07-12 13:19+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18719)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2018-07-12 13:19+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18719) [leer]
          Physische ID: 1
          Steckplatz: ChannelA-DIMM1
    *-bank:2
          Beschreibung: SODIMM DDR4 Synchron 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
          Produkt: 9905663-008.A00G
          Hersteller: Kingston
          Physische ID: 2
          Seriennummer: 88184918
          Steckplatz: ChannelB-DIMM0
          Größe: 16GiB
          Breite: 64 bits
          Takt: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
    *-bank:3
          Beschreibung: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2018-07-12 13:19+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18719)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-30 08:16+0000Last-Translator: Hendrik Knackstedt <Unknown>Language-Team: German <de@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2018-07-12 13:19+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18719) [leer]
          Physische ID: 3
          Steckplatz: ChannelB-DIMM1
  *-firmware
      Beschreibung: BIOS
      Hersteller: LENOVO
      Physische ID: e
      Version: N1CET37W (1.05 )
      date: 01/15/2016
      Größe: 128KiB
      Kapazität: 15MiB
      Fähigkeiten: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory UNGEFORDERT
      Beschreibung: Memory controller
      Produkt: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
      Hersteller: Intel Corporation
      Physische ID: 1f.2
      Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:1f.2
      Version: 21
      Breite: 32 bits
      Takt: 33MHz (30.3ns)
      Fähigkeiten: bus_master
      Konfiguration: latency=0
      Ressourcen: memory:f1244000-f1247fff
```

And

```
$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

Comment: Let's check your BIOS and your memory. In `terminal` type `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `sudo dmidecode -t 1,2` and tell me the exact brand/model # of your computer. Also show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Edit all of that output into your question, not into the comments please. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: are you able to go to virtual console by stroke STR+ALT+F3?  `sudo cat /sys/class/drm/card0/error`  And exchange your usb mouse.

Comment: Thanks @heynnema, I added the requested information to my question.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly, @nobody. Do you mean if I can to virtual console when the system freezes? I'm not sure, but I if I remember correctly, it's not possible. `sudo cat /sys/class/drm/card0/error` tells me "No error state collected" (right now). I just bought a new USB mouse and I will monitor if the problem stays. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Okay, this was empty-headed.

Comment: @yan Thanks for the data, however you forgot `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Also, please see my answer. If it's helpful, and helps solve your problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks. Report back.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Thanks @heynnema, I added the swappiness to the question. I haven't been able to try the suggestions regarding memory and BIOS, but I will. I will then report back. My system crash again a couple of minutes ago, so the problem persists.

Comment: @yan Status please...

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old version of LibreOffice; this is [more current](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/):

[image]

and I would suggest (without knowing the cause of the problem) upgrading to the latest version using these 3 steps in the event that it might correct the issue for you:

1. Add the LibreOffice PPA with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa`
2. Update your system with `sudo apt update`
3. Upgrade or install a newer LibreOffice with `sudo apt install libreoffice`

You should then be good to go.

Comment: I use the same version as the OP - it's the default version for 18.04 - and have no problems with it crashing. Do you have any evidence that upgrading will solve a crashing problem?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Other than what others have reported no. But isn't it worth a try in an effort to resolve in case there is something lurking in the background? Besides, the new version is so much better than earlier versions (which I have used on 18.04 LTS)

Comment: A search https://askubuntu.com/search?q=LibreOffice+freeze+18.04 found another user with a similar issue but no resolution yet: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201559/system-freezes-on-copying-or-pasting

Comment: @Graham it could be worth a try, but it would be nice to state explicitly that you're just suggesting something that might work without really knowing the cause of the problem. Otherwise you have the user go through a bunch of work that might not  help at all.

Comment: @OrganicMarble point taken and amended as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I see two things that need checking or updating...

**memory**

You have an odd amount of memory. In looking at `sudo lshw -C memory` I see that you have a 16G DIMM and 4G (on motherboard). Having unmatched RAM sizes means that the system cannot use memory interleaving to maximize memory speed. Assuming that you added one 16G DIMM yourself, we should run a memory test.

**Note**: Computer has maximum supported memory of 20G.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**BIOS**

**Note**: backup important files before performing a BIOS update

**Note**: confirm that I have the correct web page for your computer

You have a very old BIOS version N1CET37W (1.05) from 2016. Current version is 1.47 from 12 Dec 2019.

Go to [this web page](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t460s/20fa/20fas05p00/pc0b704z/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI) and download the newer BIOS update for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall `libreoffice-kde`, the KDE integration package for libreoffice. This will lead to your libreoffice being a bit uglier and a lot more stable.